# AppFabric 1.1 on Server 2012 Dashboard Powershell - PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell, appfabric

I have installed AppFabric onto Windows Server 2012. I checked the prerequisites were installed first and have installed accumulative update 3. I have an instance of SQL Server 2012 installed to SP1 and the OS indicates that all updates have been installed.

When viewing the dashboard I am receiving the error:

```
Unable to cast object to type 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject' to type 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Management.Data.Group...'
```

I've found minimal information during my Google searches, none of which are providing a solution to the problem.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. In the end it didn't seem to be getting in the way of the monitoring I was looking at, so I'm just living with the error.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is that the underlying PowerShell cmdlet expects to read AT LEAST ONE record from the AppFabric Persistence DB's table [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancesTable] , that is related to the WF Service(s) that the current AppFabric Dashboard is shown for.

Once you have at least one record there, the error will stop showing up (in the Dashboard of the current WF Service(s) )

---

Furthermore, in case you have WF Service in a WOW64 mode ("Enable 32-bit Applications"=TRUE on the Thread Pool of the WF Service) , then AppFabric Dashboard has another issue which is: it ignores the fact that WF Service process is in WOW64 mode and does not read the Persistence connection string from the 32-bit Framework root web.config (as it should be) , but instead reads it (wrongly) from the 64-bit Framework root web.config. Thus if you want workaround this issue, you have to manually edit the 64-bit Framework root web.config in order to substitute the Persistence connection string there with the one from the 32-bit... This will cause that the AppFabric Dashboard of any 64-bit WF Services will now stop showing the Instances info.